# Can NSArray hold NSDictionary in Objective-C/

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

Can each index of array hold the NSDictionary?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the value of an NSArray can resolve to an object identifier for an NSDictionary. However, the array doesn't "hold" the NSDictionary, nor can the index of an NSArray be an NSDictionary. An index from an Array is always an integer value.

Answer (score 4):

An NSArray can hold any type of object, so yes, putting an NSDictionary in an NSArray works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can, here is an example:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];

NSDictionary *dict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"Billy", @"Goat", @"Rover", @"Dog", nil];

NSArray *arrayWithDictionaries = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    dict1, dict2, nil];

[dict1 release];
[dict2 release];
```